# boolean retrieval, indexing phase

Tags: python, indexing

I am doing a boolean retrieval project, the first phase is indexing. I am trying to build an inverted index now. Say I got a sorted list like following: how can I merge the items

```
list = [('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),('b',1),('b',2),('b',3)...]
```

such that I can get a dictionary like the following and it remains sorted:

```
dict = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[1,2,3]...}, thx a lot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
>>> import collections
>>> mylist = [('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),('b',1),('b',2),('b',3)]
>>> result = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in mylist:
        result[item[0]].append(item[1])
>>> dict(result)
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3]}
```

`defaultdict(list)` creates a dictionary in which keys are initialised upon first access to an object created using the callable passed as the argument (in this case `list`). It avoids having to check whether the key already exists or not.

The last line converts the `defaultdict` to a normal `dict` - it is not strictly necessary as `defaultdict` behaves like a normal dictionary too.

Values are appended to each key in the same order as the original list. However, the keys themselves will not be ordered (this is a property of dictionaries).

---

**Update**: if you need the dictionary keys to remain sorted as well, you can do this:

```
>>> import collections
>>> mylist = [('a',1),('a',2),('c',1),('c',2),('b',1),('b',2)]
>>> result = collections.OrderedDict()
>>> for item in mylist:
        if item[0] not in result:
             result[item[0]] = list()
        result[item[0]].append(item[1])
>>> result
OrderedDict([('a', [1, 2]), ('c', [1, 2]), ('b', [1, 2])])
>>> result.keys()
['a', 'c', 'b']
```

Obviously, you cannot use `dict(result)` in this case as `dict` does not maintain any specific key order.

Comment: thx for your reply, actually I have known this method, the sample I gave just now is not that correct. Try this sample and check if the dictionary is still sorted list =[('&', 9), ('&', 10), ("'s", 10), ('(', 5), ('(', 6), (')', 5), (')', 6), ('+bahia', 1), (',', 1), (',', 5), (',', 6), (',', 9), (',', 10), ('-', 5), ('--', 5), ('.', 1), ('.', 5), ('.', 6), ('.', 9), ('.', 10), ('.125', 10), ('0.39', 1), ('0.99', 5), ('1', 9), ('1,655.8', 6), ('1,750', 1), ('1,780', 1), ('1,850', 1), ('1,870', 1), ('1,875', 1), ('1,880', 1), ('1.06', 1), ('1.24', 5)]

Comment: ah, you want the dictionary keys to remain sorted as well? Will update the answer then...